# Is there a way to allow users to copy a folder into a shared folder, but not have access to any other folders in that shared folder?

Tags: windows, permissions

I am writing a login script using .bat files. As a part of this script, I am trying to mimic one of the functions of AD, mapping a drive on login. We currently use this to map `P:` to the user's personal drive, which is stored at `\\server\Users`.

After running a test under a user profile to see if I could create a folder called `\\server\Users\Username`, I found that users do not have access to create folders in `\\server\Users`. I can't open up permissions on this folder too much, but if there is a way to allow users to copy a folder pre-loaded with all the right permissions into that drive, and then retain permissions on that folder, it may be a small enough opening that it could work.

Is there a way to allow users to copy a folder and retain permissions on that folder, without granting any other access to the shared folder?

To answer the most common question related to login scripts using batch files, due to how our IT department works, Group Policies are not an option.

Comment: In general for newer Servers, AD Security prevents that. Only the User and a Domain Administrator have access to a specific User folder.

Comment: @John Right, and it's definitely a newer server. I'm trying to create the user folder, but I'm under the impression that the permissions required for a user to outright make a folder in the shared folder are higher than the permissions required to copy something into it.

Comment: The User permissions are different (not necessarily higher) that is preventing you from copying into. I am assuming you are not the Domain Admin.

Comment: That is correct, I am not the domain admin. I have admin rights, just not that level.

Comment: Server security is very tight (assuming it to be properly installed) so I do not think you will be able to copy files into locations without permission.